# パッケージのインストール

Tags: r

よろしくお願いいたします。

統計ソフトRで，miclustパッケージをインストールしようとし，以下のコードを打ち込みました（作成者のHPからコピーしたものです）．

> ```
> local({
>   info <- loadingNamespaceInfo()
>   pkg <- info$pkgname
>   ns <- .getNamespace(as.name(pkg))
>   if (is.null(ns))
>     stop("cannot find namespace environment for ", pkg, domain = NA);
>   dbbase <- file.path(info$libname, pkg, "R", pkg)
>   lazyLoad(dbbase, ns, filter = function(n) n != ".__NAMESPACE__.")
> })
> ```

しかし，以下のメッセージが出てしまい，パッケージのインストールに失敗をしてしまいます．
これは，どのようにして良いでしょうか．
あるいは，このほかにも，miclustパッケージをインストールする方法はあるのでしょうか．ご教示のほど，よろしくお願いいたします。

```
> local({
+   info <- loadingNamespaceInfo()
+   pkg <- info$pkgname
+   ns <- .getNamespace(as.name(pkg))
+   if (is.null(ns))
+     stop("cannot find namespace environment for ", pkg, domain = NA);
+   dbbase <- file.path(info$libname, pkg, "R", pkg)
+   lazyLoad(dbbase, ns, filter = function(n) n != ".__NAMESPACE__.")
+ })
Error in dynGet("__LoadingNamespaceInfo__", stop("not loading a namespace")) : 
   名前空間をロードしません
```

Answer (score 2):

https://www.isglobal.org/software
から
Package source. miclust_1.2.5.tar.gz
をダウンロードしてローカルからインストールできませんか？
ローカルからインストールするには，Rstudioであれば，
Tools > install packages
で，install fromでpackage archiveを選ぶと良いです。

Comment: hideaki様
ご助言ありがとうございました．
問題は解決し，無事にインストールすることができました．